# How to replace text in content control after, XML binding using docx4j

Tags: replace, newline, docx4j

I am using docx4j 2.8.1 with Content Controls in my .docx file. I can replace the CustomXML part by injecting my own XML and then calling `BindingHandler.applyBindings` after supplying the input XML. I can add a token in my XML such as `¶` then I would like to replace that token in the MainDocumentPart, but using that approach, when I iterate through the content in the MainDocumentPart with [**this** (link)](http://java.dzone.com/articles/create-complex-word-docx) method none of my text from my XML is even in the collection extracted from the MainDocumentPart. I am thinking that even after binding the XML, it remains separate from the MainDocumentPart (??)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this with anything more than a little test doc yet. My token is the Pilcrow: `¶`. Since it's a single character, it won't be split in separate runs. My code is:

```
private void injectXml (WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage) throws JAXBException {
    MainDocumentPart part = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    String xml = XmlUtils.marshaltoString(part.getJaxbElement(), true);
    xml = xml.replaceAll("¶", "</w:t><w:br/><w:t>");
    Object obj = XmlUtils.unmarshalString(xml);
    part.setJaxbElement((Document) obj);
}
```

The pilcrow character comes from the XML and is injected by applying the XML bindings to the content controls. The problem is that the content from the XML does not seem to be in the MainDocumentPart so the replace doesn't work.

(Using docx4j 2.8.1)

Comment: FWIW, although I'm not currently using content bindings, I do a very similar thing when converting inbound line breaks (the data is plain text and HTML content authored elsewhere). Just so you know you're not alone ;-)

Comment: 2021 and that is still relevant. This was very helpful for me, thanks!